# Link array values to object member variables

Tags: c++, arrays, hyperlink

I need to have an `array` of `double` link to member variables in some objects. There can be multiple objects, but the member variables linked to will always be `double`.

For example:

```
Foo foo;
foo.x = 3.2;

Bar bar;
bar.y = 1.1;
bar.z = 2.0;

double arrayValues[2] = {foo.x, bar.y};
```

Now, when I change a `arrayValues` value, I want to easily make the corresponding member variable in `foo` or `bar` to change. I want `arrayValues` to be any length and constructed from any set of member variables.

I was thinking about having a second `array` of `pointer`, which would correspond with `arrayValues`. For example:

```
double* linkArray[2] = {&foo.x, &bar.y};
```

Then whenever I change a value in `arrayValues`, I change the corresponding value in `linkArray`:

```
arrayValues[i] = 4.4;
*linkArray[i] = arrayValues[i];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to have an array of double link to member variables in some objects.

You can't do that.

The closest thing to that would be to use an array of `std::reference<double>`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo { double x; };
struct Bar { double y; double z; };

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   foo.x = 3.2;

   Bar bar;
   bar.y = 1.1;
   bar.z = 2.0;

   std::reference_wrapper<double> arrayValues[] = {{foo.x}, {bar.y}};
   arrayValues[0] *= 2;
   std::cout << arrayValues[0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
6.4
6.4
```

Comment: What I mean is that I need to provide a link between an `array` of `double` and member variables. The array is an input to an external optimization algorithm, so I can't change its type.